# How come when using KNN on an imbalanced dataset, setting scoring='recall' turns all my probabilities to binary?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, imblearn

I am dealing with a very sparse, and imbalanced dataset that i am reducing the dimensionality of with pca, then feeding that into a knn classifier. I cannot use SMOTE or the imblearn package in this case and simple upsampling hasnt helped much so I'm not looking to correct the imbalance right now.  I am also interested more in the output of my model's `.predict_proba()` than its actual predictions.

When I fit the model with `scoring='roc_auc'`, the output of `knn.predict_proba(test_X)` are continuous float values between 0 and 1, just as I'd expect.  However, when I set `scoring='recall'` in an effort to predict the minority class better, the output of `knn.predict_proba(test_X)` is all either `0.00001` or `1.00000` and I dont understand why.  If i do the same with a gradient boosted decision tree classifier that I built for the same problem, it still outputs continuous values when I use `scoring='roc_auc'`.

My best guess is that there just arent enough cases of the minority class in this dataset and it partly has something to do with knn being a topological method.

I want to understand what could be making this happen.

```
pca = PCA()
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca', pca), ('knn', knn)])
#Define Parameters
param_grid = {
     'pca__n_components': [4, 7, 10, 20, 82],
     'knn__n_neigbors': [1,3,5,7,15],
     'knn__weights': ['uniform', 'distance'] 
     }
search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=10, verbose=3, scoring='recall')
======================================================================================
best_params_: {'pca__n_components': 82, 
               'knn__n_neighbors': 15, 
               'knn__weights': 'uniform'}
```

Comment: `KNeighborsClassifier` doesn't have a `scoring` parameter...are you doing a hyperparameter search?

Comment: Yes this was inside of  `search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=10, verbose=3, scoring='recall')`.  I didnt know it didnt have a `scoring` parameter... it runs but its definitely changing something. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Please add that and the definition of `pipe` and `param_grid` to the question, as well as the `best_params_` resulting from the searches.  (A minimal representative example would be best, but those pieces of information might be enough to provide an answer.)

Comment: Your question seems to indicate that problems occur because of the `recall` scoring, but what would the best hyperparameters be when setting it to accuracy, which is default?

Comment: When scoring is set to `'accuracy'` the best parameters are `{'pca__n_components': 82, 'knn__n_neighbors': 5, 'knn__weights': 'uniform'}`.  Also the probabilities are different when I use `accuracy`, instead of being a broad range of continuous values or binary they are either `0.0` `0.2` `0.4` `0.6` `0.8`.  If `KNeighborsClassifier` has no `scoring` parameter, what is changing?

Comment: @JacobMyer, KNeighborsClassifier doesn't have `scoring`, but your `GridSearchCV` does.  For `accuracy`, since the chosen `n_neighbors` is 5, you're averaging 5 numbers in {0,1} so you can only get one of those values.  You still haven't reported the best parameters for `roc_auc` scoring, but the `recall` best_params don't give an obvious cause for the discrete probabilities...